# Printing the sum of four different list of floats?

Tags: python, list

Currently, i have four list and i want to sum them up into one list.

```
L1 = [2.3,4.5,6.9]
L2 = [1.2,3.5,5.4]
L3 = [12.1,6.8,2.4]
L4 = [15.2,5.9,11.7]
```

That would give me:

```
newList = [30.8,20.7,26.4]
```

I looked up many methods utilising `zips` but I'm looking for a method to do it the long way. If there aren't any convenient method, I wouldn't mind using zips but just being curious.

Basically i would create a new list but i wasn't able to figure the sum part.

```
newL = []
for val in L1:
    for val in L2:??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all four lists have the same length, alternative solutions are:

- list comprehensions:

  ```
  sumsList = [L1[i]+L2[i]+L3[i]+L4[i] for i in range(len(L1))]
  ```

  **or**, an alternative solution, far more elegant, in my opinion:

  ```
  someList = [L1,L2,L3,L4]
  sumsList = [sum([l[i] for l in someList]) for i in range(len(L1))]
  ```
- `for-in` loops:

  ```
  sumsList = []
  for i in range(len(L1)):
      sumsList.append(L1[i]+L2[i]+L3[i]+L4[i])
  ```

Result: `[30.799999999999997, 20.700000000000003, 26.4]`

Best part: does not use `zip()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use zip like this:

```
[sum(t) for t in zip(L1, L2, L3, L4)]
# [30.799999999999997, 20.700000000000003, 26.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L = [[2.3, 4.5, 6.9],
...     [1.2, 3.5, 5.4],
...     [12.1, 6.8, 2.4],
...     [15.2, 5.9, 11.7]]
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*L)))
[30.799999999999997, 20.700000000000003, 26.399999999999999]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `map`, `sum` and `zip`:

```
list_sums = map(sum, zip(L1,L2,L3,L4))
# [30.799999999999997, 20.700000000000003, 26.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the end product then a tuple is constructed much faster than a list, expressing tuple() before a generator as below:

```
total_of_each_element = tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(L1,L2,L3,L4))
```

will achieve this, here's my code

```
L1 = [2.3,4.5,6.9]
L2 = [1.2,3.5,5.4]
L3 = [12.1,6.8,2.4]
L4 = [15.2,5.9,11.7]

total_of_each_element = tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(L1,L2,L3,L4))
print (total_of_each_element)
```

prints:

```
(30.799999999999997, 20.700000000000003, 26.4)
```

to round it:

```
total_of_each_element = tuple(round(sum(t),2) for t in zip(L1,L2,L3,L4))
print (total_of_each_element)
```

prints:

```
(30.8, 20.7, 26.4)
```

alternatively, make all lists the same length, adding zeros to the shorter ones:

```
lists = [L1,L2,L3,L4]
longest = len(max(lists,key=len))
for lst in lists:
    if len(lst) < longest:
        n = longest - len(lst)
        for i in range(n):
            lst.append(0)
```

then total and round with a for loop:

```
total_of_each_element = []
for i in range(longest):
    total_of_each_element.append(round((L1[i]+L2[i]+L3[i]+L4[i]),2))
print (total_of_each_element)
```

prints:

```
[30.8, 20.7, 26.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `zip` would be the best answer...

```
newList = [a + b + c + d for a,b,c,d in zip(L1,L2,L3,L4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.You just change them to numpy array and do simple addition.

```
import numpy as np
print np.array(L1)+np.array(L2)+np.array(L3)+np.array(L4)
```